# Special link for no automatic login (no username and no password)

Tags: login, wp-login-form

My goal is:

Login to different wordpress sites of mine without any steps other then pressing a link.

So for example the link will be:

```
https:/domain.com/wp-login.php?username="admin"&password="Hadfieiw9cu#$4asdfk@iI*fSfaeeofokffd"
```

Something like that. a way to give a link with code inside it that will make automatic login to the wp admin.

Now there is a plugin that does this:
[Auto login links](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autologin-links/), but this isn't so secure.

I would like to use the username and password way, but only shortent the login process by entering the username and password in the link and not having to type them in the login form and click "login".

Any ideas how to accomplish this kind of goal?

Comment: There are big security problems here, but worst, having the username and password in the URL means  your passwords get stored cleartext in your Apache/Nginx logs and anywhere else the link goes That on its own would breach many data protection laws, and be grounds for legal action from customers and consumers for failing to safeguard their data. Every magic link implementation I know of uses nonces and single use tokens, and even then it's as a confirmation/validation step not a complete login step. Put simply, any plugin that does this wont be so secure because it's an insecure thing to do

Comment: Maybe mainwp is an option for you. Self-Hosted Master Dashboard for all sites. https://mainwp.com/

Comment: The links aren't suppose to be anywhere and not be used by others. only me on my mac.